# Hoard allocator not "working"?

Tags: c++, memory-management, hoard

I'm trying to Hoard allocator to work, but it seems it doesn't. I have a benchmark application that does a lot of dynamic memory management. The execution time for Hoard and glibc memory manager is the same. It makes me wonder if I'm doing the right thing.

What I do is...

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/path/libhoard.so"

g++ main.cpp -O3 -o bm -lpthread -lrt
```

Shouldn't I have to link to Hoard allocator? Does it matter what path (in LD_PRELOAD) is, or can I have whatever path?

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04, and g++ 4.2.4

Cheers

---

No one knows any Linux command (such as grep) to find out if Hoard is loaded properly, and is the actual allocator used?

Comment: You are not really using /path, are you?  Substitute the actual path.

Comment: Of course not. :-) I was wondering if it was mandatory to have it e.g. in /usr/local/lib or similar

Answer (score 6):

Author of [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) here.

(a) Any path for LD_PRELOAD is fine (as long as it is correct).

(b) To see whether your code is using Hoard or not, use the `ldd` command. If everything went according to plan, then you will see the Hoard library (notice the second line after the second invocation of ldd).

Best,

-- Emery Berger

```
bash-3.2$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe6dfd000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003159600000)
 libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x000000315e200000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000000315d200000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003154e00000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003155a00000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003154a00000)
 libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003162000000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003155600000)
 libsepol.so.1 => /lib64/libsepol.so.1 (0x000000315ce00000)
bash-3.2$ export LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libhoard.so
bash-3.2$ ldd /bin/ls
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff24bfd000)
 /nfs/cm/users1/emery/scratch/projects/hoard/trunk/src/libhoard.so (0x00002b4885f42000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003159600000)
 libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x000000315e200000)
 libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000000315d200000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003154e00000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003155600000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003155a00000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000315b200000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003155200000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000315aa00000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003154a00000)
 libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003162000000)
 libsepol.so.1 => /lib64/libsepol.so.1 (0x000000315ce00000)
bash-3.2$
```